# Error occurs in the template of component EmployeeCreateComponent

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-httpclient

I'm new to Angular and working on `httpclient` and `httpservice` project of CRUD application. While compiling with `ng serve` in VS code I get the following error:

> error: ERROR in src/app/employee-create/employee-create.component.html:18:65 - error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

**employee-create.component.html**

```
<div class="container custom-container">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h3 class="mb-3 text-center">Create Employee</h3>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="employeeDetails.name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="employeeDetails.email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="employeeDetails.phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" (click)="addEmployee()">Create Employee</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**employee-create component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { RestApiService } from "../shared/rest-api.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-create',
  templateUrl: './employee-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-create.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeCreateComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() employeeDetails = { name: '', email: '', phone: 0 }

  constructor(
    public restApi: RestApiService, 
    public router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  addEmployee() {
    this.restApi.createEmployee(this.employeeDetails).subscribe((data: {}) => {
      this.router.navigate(['/employees-list'])
    })
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
addEmployee() { // <=== dataEmployee Parameter     this.restApi.createEmployee(this.employeeDetails).subscribe((data: {}) => {
    this.router.navigate(['/employees-list'])
  })
}
```

you are not passing a Parameter in Html file but you are trying to get parameter in ts that's why you are getting Error.

Answer (score 2):

The error is obvious in your template `addEmployee()` method on button click doesnt have any param.

```
(click)="addEmployee()"
```

But in your component you are passing `dataEmployee` param in `addEmployee(dataEmployee)` method (which looks like not in use).

Hence you can remove `dataEmployee` param from `addEmployee()` method.

```
addEmployee() { // <=== no dataEmployee param
  this.restApi.createEmployee(this.employeeDetails).subscribe((data: {}) => {
    this.router.navigate(['/employees-list'])
  })
}
```